# The requested URL could not be retrieved error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat

I'm trying to do some tutorials using Eclipse IDE. But every time I try to run a page on the server(Apache Tomcat v8.0) this error comes up.

> ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> ---
>
> While trying to retrieve the URL: /test/test-tags.jsf
>
> The following error was encountered:
>
> Invalid URL  Some aspect of the requested URL is incorrect. Possible
>   problems:
>
> Missing or incorrect access protocol (should be `http://'' or similar)
>   Missing hostname  Illegal double-escape in the URL-Path  Illegal
>   character in hostname; underscores are not allowed

**Web Project Info:**
**Target Runtime               :** *Apache Tomcat v8.0*
**Dynamic Web Module Version   :** *3.0*
**Configuration                :** *Java Server Faces v2.2*

Comment: Which URL exactly was you using then? In any way, you shouldn't be using Eclipse's builtin browser. This isn't designed for real web developers. Just open the page directly in your favourite browser. E.g. Chrome or Firefox. A sane one has a builtin HTTP traffic monitor which you can pop by pressing F12 and selecting the "Network" tab.

Comment: @BalusC thanks a lot.. opening the page from Chrome worked out.. :D The built-in browser doesn't work i guess. I was really going out of my mind with this thing... It's hard to learn JSF all alone. If you happen to know any good beginners tutorials on JSF can you post some links? That would be really helpful. Thank you very much again.. :)

Comment: Hover with your mouse the `[jsf]` tag below the question until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing web pages in Eclipse, do **not** use its builtin browser. Just start the server and open the page in a real browser like Chrome or Firefox.